# Better way of doing things? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, class

I have the following codes. However this code is repeated many times on different Userforms. However what changes in this code is the name of all objects as it is on different userform

```
Sub FirstOne ()
Call RunFast_Begin
    Me.Position_MYORG = ""
    Select Case Me.TheORG
        Case ""
            Position_elswhere.Visible = False
            'Small text informing the user it needs to select the Branch
            Branch_TEXT.Visible = False
            'Dropdown list of branch and regions at my Org
            Branch.Visible = False
            'Small text informing the user needs to select the Position
            Position_TEXT.Visible = False
            'Dropdown for My OrgPositions
            Position_MYORG.Visible = False
            'Positions drop down for known
            Postion_Drop_Down_Elsewhere.Visible = False

    '* For all departments where there are many positions *
        Case "My Org"
            Me.Position_MYORG.RowSource = "MYORG"
            'in case user selected wrong option first
            Position_elswhere.Visible = False
           Postion_Drop_Down_Elsewhere.Visible = False
            'My Org info
            Branch_TEXT.Visible = True
            Branch.Visible = True
            Position_TEXT.Visible = True
            Position_MYORG.Visible = True
End Select
        Call RunFast_End
        End sub
```

So on another userform the same code would appear but as follow:

```
Sub SecondOne()
Call RunFast_Begin
    Me.Position_MYORG2 = ""
    Select Case Me.TheORG2
        Case ""
            Position_elswhere2.Visible = False
            'Small text informing the user it needs to select the Branch
            Branch_TEXT2.Visible = False
            'Dropdown list of branch and regions at My Org
            Branch2.Visible = False
            'Small text informing the user needs to select the Position
            Position_TEXT2.Visible = False
            'Dropdown for My OrgPositions
            Position_MYORG2.Visible = False
            'Positions drop down for known
            Postion_Drop_Down_Elsewhere2.Visible = False

    '* For all departments where there are many positions *
        Case "My Org"
            Me.Position_MYORG2.RowSource = "MYORG"
            'in case user selected wrong option first
            Position_elswhere2.Visible = False
           Postion_Drop_Down_Elsewhere2.Visible = False
            'My Org info
            Branch_TEXT2.Visible = True
            Branch2.Visible = True
            Position_TEXT2.Visible = True
            Position_MYORG2.Visible = True
       End select 
Call RunFast_End
           End sub
```

As you can imagine it is a pain when I need to make a change... this code is on three different Userform and on those it appears 5 times so basically I have to make 15 changes everytime one little thing is changed.

I heard about functions and class, but have no idea, even after youtubing it how I can match my situation to those. I know I'm not supposed to ask for coding, but my coding works, that's not the issue here. I'm just trying to work smarter and make my coding less cumbersome for me :-)

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thank you so much

Comment: Controls on a form can be accessed by name using (eg) `Me.Controls("myTextBox1")`.  Refactor your code to a Sub which takes a numeric argument, and use that to refer to each "set" of controls (eg) `Me.Controls("Branch_TEXT" & num)`

Comment: Mathieu, the reason why is because each label has a controlsource to a specific cell in different worksheet. I'll take a look at the link you provided and see if this helps. Thanks

Comment: Tim, this might be exactly what I was looking for, the syntax seems to do the tricks, however I'm not quite sure how I would use this or where to put that in a code. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an abbreviated version of what I'm talking about:

```
Sub SetUpControls(frm As Object, i As Long)
    RunFast_Begin
    frm.Controls("Position_MYORG" & i) = ""
    Select Case frm.Controls("TheORG" & i)
        Case ""

            frm.Controls("Position_elswhere" & i).Visible = False
            frm.Controls("Branch_TEXT" & i).Visible = False
            'etc
        Case "My Org"
            frm.Controls("Position_MYORG" & i).RowSource = "MYORG"
            frm.Controls("Position_elswhere" & i).Visible = False
            'etc...
    End Select
    RunFast_End
End Sub
```

From any form you could call this like:

```
SetUpControls Me, 2
```